# How to change size of image in a active jQuery UI Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs, and have an image inside the anchor of each tab list item (li).  What I want to happen is for the image size to be a certain size for each inactive tab, and a larger size for the single active tab.  I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm not great with javascript and can't figure out how to get the script's if statement (see below) to be correct...all I was thinking I needed to do was to make it so that when there's a selected tab, the image inside that tab gets the larger dimensions.

Here's the script that I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

         if( $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active').attr('active') ) {
             $('.theLogo').css({'width' : '120px' , 'height' : '60px'});
         }
         else {
            $('.theLogo').css({'width' : '90px' , 'height' : '45px'});
         };

     });
 </script>
```

Here's the HTML for the tabs:

```
  <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="picture1.png" alt="Picture 1" name="photo" id="photo" class="theLogo" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2"><img src="picture2.png" alt="Picture 2" name="photo2" id="photo2" class="theLogo" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3"><img src="picture3.png" alt="Picture 3" name="photo3" id="photo3" class="theLogo" /></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                  <iframe class="resultFrame" src="http://www.fakesite123.net"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                    <iframe class="resultFrame" src="http://www.fakesite1234.net"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3">
                    <iframe class="resultFrame" src="http://www.fakesite1235.net"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you must do it with JS?

```
ul#tabs li a img {width: 90px; height: 45px;}
ul#tabs li.ui-tabs-active a img {width: 120px; height: 60px;}
```

Comment: LOL...see below...I just realized that I can use CSS.  Thanks for posting though!

Comment: Thanks. And a +1 for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by using CSS instead of javascript.  I put the following CSS:

```
 .ui-state-default img {
     width:90px;
     height:45px;
 }
 .ui-state-active img {
     width:120px;
     height:60px;
 }
```

I hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem.

Anyone that finds a javascript solution for this is more than welcome to post it!